# Finding a random WxH rectangle fitting in a MxN array region, where array[x][y] == number

Tags: random

I'm programming a game where a random map is generated whenever a new game is started. The game field is a MxN boolean array (true=ground, false=air.) From that array I calculate each connected free (air) regions, generating a new MxN int array where the int value is 0 if there's is ground, or the region number if it's free space (each free space has the same region # as their neighbour free spaces.) Now my random playfield has been separated in numbered rooms.

E.g.:
**Ground data:**
00000**11**00**111**000
0000**11**00000**111**0
000**111**00000**1111**
00000**111**000000**1**
0000000**11**0000**11**

**Room data:**
11111**00**22**000**333
1111**00**22222**000**3
111**000**22222**0000**
11111**000**222222**0**
1111111**00**2222**00**

I need to populate these rooms with monsters, object, etc. so I need some way to find, given a rectangle size and a room #, a random place inside that room where the WxH rectangle would fit.

Obviously I could just blindly try random coordinates until the criteria is matched, but I don't think that's really the way to go, because it may take ages for the random number to meet the requirements (or not, it's random.)

I don't care if the random region is reusable later, I mean, I don't care if the same random region can be randomly selected twice (in other words, if objects spawn on top of other objects), but it would be preferable to be able to handle that situation too.

Thanks :)

Comment: Would it work to randomly place the objects first and then generate the terrain by "growing out" from their positions?

Comment: It could work, but I would have to rewrite the terrain generator and the deadline for this project is arriving. Thanks for the idea anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a list of valid positions for the objects (using logic similar to your room-determination algorithm), and randomly select an index into that list.

Comment: I decided to do this, although I was afraid I could have some memory problems. The list of accepted points can get pretty big, but with bigger game field I just get more rooms, not bigger rooms, so the list size is the same for any field size. It works like a charm, and it's faster than I thought it would be.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a third MxN array that has a 0 or 1 in each spot. 0 means a WxH would not fit there and 1 means it would. This should be calculated at the same (or really, right after the time) you create the second array,